# Mail change in FirefoxSync

Tags: firefox

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 and Firefox.

Long ago (5+ years) I created FirefoxSync account. Today I logged into it, and Firefox sent mail to recognize login from new device. I have to change mail assigned to FS account.

How?

Comment: Did you forget the existing e-mail's password, or do you simply want to migrate your existing information to a new e-mail address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, from the [mozilla forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1040707?db=5):

> changing the email address isn't an option.

Sorry!